# HTTP GET from Restlet server returned compressed (?) data

Tags: axios, gzip, restlet

I am writing a Node.js app to get info from a server.

A successful HTTP GET returned a response that seems to have compressed data.

Below is the response header:

```
AxiosHeaders {
  date: 'Tue, 13 Dec 2022 02:35:30 GMT',
  server: 'Restlet-Framework/2.4.2',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains',
  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
  'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
  vary: 'Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Accept',
  'x-mag': 'FF544D89FCC0751E;8315c9c1;481618;usrLkup->0;usrBase->0;getPRBefFind->0;getPRBefFind->0;PRAfterFind->0;D-IDM_REST_UMHS_IDV;usrLkup->0;usrBase->0;SendSoapStart->0;SendSoapExit->289;NRLEnd->289;Oauth-IDM_REST_UMHS_IDV;default;SH;FF1End->289;SendSoapStart->289;SendSoapExit->510;EvalII->510;AH;FP2->510;WS=415c128d;default;FP4->819;',
  'set-cookie': [
    'ZNPCQ003-32353400=415c128d; Path=/o-umhsIDV; Domain=.med.umich.edu'
  ],
  via: '1.1 ...server-name... (Access Gateway-ag-FF544D89FCC0751E-481618)',
  'keep-alive': 'timeout=300, max=100',
  connection: 'Keep-Alive',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
}
```

The data in the response is 1192 bytes of:

```
��"�����w$;����><(��x�
```

It seems that the response header is missing a `Content-Encoding`. Does that cause Axios to not process the data properly?

Thank you for any thoughts / comments.

The result is expected to be JSON.

I tried to use zlib to decompress the data. But various methods (gunzip, unzip. deflate, ...) all resulted in error with the data.

Comment: it was defect axios v 1.2.0. It fixed v1.2.1. Search in this site.

Answer (score 1):

@[Bench Vue] is right. I updated the Axios package to 1.2.1 with a `npm i axios`. My app started working. Many thanks!